# npm install error in vue

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, centos

Just in following along with a tutorial, That's the version information.

```
[root@localhost my-project]# node -v
v6.11.3

[root@localhost my-project]# npm -v
3.10.10

[root@localhost my-project]# vue --version
2.9.2

[root@localhost my-project]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

just run with easy command, and there nothing program running on 8080 port.

```
npm install --global vue-cli
vue init webpack my-project
cd my-project
npm install
npm run dev
```

then npm install output error, does it mean its not finish to install?

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.1 (node_modules/sane/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/mocha-nightwatch-2017d835/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected control character at 75:30
npm ERR!     "Diogo Monteiro <diogo.gmtps://github.com/diogogmt)",
npm ERR!                              ^
npm ERR! File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/mocha-nightwatch-2017d835/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/htdocs/my-project/npm-debug.log
```

proceed to do install,i don't know what's wrong with some `package.json` ,I never change any code in the install progress. just delete the dir `node_modules` and run `npm install` again. got this error in log file.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.1 (node_modules/sane/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/babel-generator/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 51:7
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "s
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:       ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-547cad6c/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 30:32
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "John Gozde <john@gozde.ca>
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                                ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-041921dc/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-merge-idents/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected token '\u0000' at 37:44
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Jamie Wong <jamie.lf.wong@gmail.com>",
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                                            ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-9b0e6bda/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-calc/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 41:35
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "djchie <djchie.dev@gmail.com>
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                                   ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-33433b36/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 53:6
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "including
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:      ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-f9948a11/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-merge-longhand/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 37:12
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Jamie 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:            ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-90819b54/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-merge-rules/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 35:43
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Chris Truter <jeffpalentine@gmail.commail.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                                           ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-c81f99e5/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-convert-values/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected token '\u0000' at 41:3
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:   
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:   ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-c4ef212e/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/source-map-support/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 27:33
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Jmeas Smith <jellyes2@gmail
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                                 ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-1ba31f57/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 38:31
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Eddy Bruël <ejpbruel@mozi
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                               ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-a73d7829/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/escodegen/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 49:17
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:   "main": "./sou
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                 ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-fa0ade6a/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-filter-plugins/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 32:41
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Chris Montgomery <christopher.montg
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                                         ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-6667251c/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-discard-duplicates/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 42:30
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Gary Ye <garysye@gmail.c
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                              ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-6dc27f9d/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-discard-empty/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 39:22
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Hawken Rives <ha
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                      ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-2f42160e/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/istanbul-lib-source-maps/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 43:26
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Nicolas Lalevée <ni
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                          ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-0b5539fd/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-minify-gradients/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 32:9
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Chr
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:         ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-6a529f9a/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-normalize-url/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected token '\u0000' at 33:43
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "J. Ryan Stinnett <jryans@gmail.com>",
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                                           ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-4d9551e4/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-svgo/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 29:10
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "azu 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:          ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-59f8c189/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 34:32
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Jack Herrington <jherringt
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                                ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-dd8026aa/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 28:25
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Michael Z Goddard <
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                         ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-9d53ffe4/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-discard-unused/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 40:12
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Gilad 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:            ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-5a8bff21/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-ordered-values/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 33:11
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "J. Ry
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:           ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-67b135eb/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-minify-params/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 35:11
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Chris�=#G�
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:           ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-7d27255f/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-minify-font-values/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 36:29
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Daniel Espeset <daniel@
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                             ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-8d7d0bab/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-normalize-charset/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 31:30
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Adam Kirkton <akirkton@t
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                              ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-95425f09/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: source-map@0.5.7 (node_modules/postcss-zindex/node_modules/source-map):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected token '\u0000' at 66:5
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:   }
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/source-map-e57425b7/package.json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: mocha-nightwatch@3.2.2 (node_modules/mocha-nightwatch):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Failed to parse json
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unexpected control character at 58:18
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:     "Charles Lowe
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:                  ^
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/mocha-nightwatch-2017d835/package.json
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/arr-flatten-425e9bea/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected control character at 52:7
npm ERR!     "r
npm ERR!       ^
npm ERR! File: /opt/htdocs/my-project/node_modules/.staging/arr-flatten-425e9bea/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/htdocs/my-project/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: The error points you to the exact place in your package.json. Make sure it is valid json

Comment: BTW - You open the email with `<` and close with `)` - it may cause the issue

Comment: @IgalS.: The `package.json` the error is occuring in is in the `mocha-nightwatch` package and not in his `package.json` itself…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of your package.json files corrupted:

```
Diogo Monteiro <diogo.gmtps://github.com/diogogmt)
```

The missing text is `ail.com> (ht` was lost when NPM was fetching Mocha-Nightwatch from the repository.

I would delete the file `node_modules/.staging/mocha-nightwatch-2017d835/package.json` and run `npm install` again.